# external jars in maven spring mvc

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-2

Hi I am trying to use the 
https://github.com/skrymer/qrbuilder

as extenal dependency in my project so i created a Jar file and qrbuilder-1.1.jar and added this jar to my project lib folder and then added dependency in pom.xml as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrbuilder</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/qrbuilder-1.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Added and when i try to use the class given

```
    public  String generateQRCode(String data){
    QRCBuilder<BufferedImage> qrCodeBuilder = new ZXingQRCodeBuilder();

    String base64String = null; 
    try {
        qrCodeBuilder.newQRCode()
        .withSize(250, 250)
            .and()
        .withData(data)
            .and()
        .decorate(colorizeQRCode(Color.black.darker()))
            .and()
        .decorate(addImageOverlay(ImageIO.read(new File("src/main/resources/files/images/qr_logo.png")), 1f, 0.25f))
            .and()
        .doVerify(true)
        .toImage();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write( (RenderedImage) qrCodeBuilder, "png", baos );
        baos.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        base64String= Base64.encodeBase64String(imageInByte);
        return base64String;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return base64String;
}
```

when i try to use this code am getting class not found exceptions

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/skrymer/qrbuilder/QRCBuilder
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1868)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
... 116 more
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.skrymer.qrbuilder.QRCBuilder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    ... 135 more

is there any problem while adding a jar to my project or how can solve this problem..

am able to use the class but while running the tomcat getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) of maven scope:

> system This scope is similar to provided except that you have to
>   provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always
>   available and is not looked up in a repository.

The libs in this scope will not be bundled in the artefact. You have to put it manually in your classpath for your Environment on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this as a dependency either add it to your maven repository using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

or add it to a local repository by downloading the file and adding it to your project.

```
<repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>localrepository</id>
         <url>file://${basedir}/repo</url>
      </repository>
```

Comment: Thanks Essess Boy, I have added that repository to my pom.xml but still the same issue am getting

Comment: @ShivaPrasadG you need the correct directory structure, something like com/my/app/qrbuilder/qr/1.1/com-my-app-qrbuilder-1.1.jar